# Speeding up query with `order by`, `limit` and `union`

Tags: postgresql, indexing, union

I have a problem with a view that works as a “directory” of information from other tables. I cannot get PostgreSQL (11.4) to use an index when querying such a view with `unions` and `left join`.

First, here's a simplified version without the `left join`:

```sql
create table t1 (
  id uuid,
  n int,
  updated timestamp
);
create index i1 on t1 (updated);

create table t2 (
  id uuid,
  n int,
  updated timestamp
);
create index i2 on t2 (updated);

create or replace view directory as (
    select * from t1
  union all
    select * from t2
);
```

In the following tests, 10,000 rows were added to each table.

When querying this view with an `order by` and a `limit`, everything works well, and the `i1` and `i2` indices are used:

```sql
select *
from directory
order by updated desc
limit 10;
```

[image: Plan visualized by PEV]

Plan: https://lpaste.com/KWcGXlAoEy

However, if a `left join` is used in the view, the `i2` index will no longer be used:

```sql
create table aux2 (
  id uuid,
  x text
);
create index auxi2 on aux2 (id);

drop view directory;
create view directory as (
    select t1.id, t1.n, t1.updated, null from t1
  union all
    select t2.id, t2.n, t2.updated, a.x from t2
    left join aux2 a on a.id = t2.id              -- ✱
);
```

In this case, a sequential scan is done on `t2`:

```sql
select *
from directory
order by updated desc
limit 10;
```

[image: Plan visualized by PEV]

Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=916.89..917.19 rows=10 width=44) (actual time=6.128..6.135 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=141
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=916.89..1516.89 rows=20000 width=44) (actual time=6.127..6.132 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: t1.updated DESC
        Buffers: shared hit=141
        ->  Index Scan Backward using i1 on t1  (cost=0.29..375.29 rows=10000 width=60) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=10 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Sort  (cost=916.60..941.60 rows=10000 width=29) (actual time=6.122..6.122 rows=1 loops=1)
              Sort Key: t2.updated DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=138
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=289.00..600.50 rows=10000 width=29) (actual time=2.240..4.956 rows=10000 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (t2.id = a.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=138
                    ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..174.00 rows=10000 width=28) (actual time=0.005..0.807 rows=10000 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=74
                    ->  Hash  (cost=164.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=17) (actual time=2.227..2.227 rows=10000 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 607kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=64
                          ->  Seq Scan on aux2 a  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=17) (actual time=0.004..1.092 rows=10000 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=64
Planning Time: 0.295 ms
Execution Time: 6.161 ms
```

It's not the `left join` alone that precludes PostgreSQL from using `i2` here. If the view does not contain a `union` (i.e. we only do the `select` + `left join` from `t2` and `aux2`), the `i2` index is used.

What's a better way to do this?

I'm both surprised that the planner doesn't use the `i2` index, but also that the `limit` + `order by` isn't passed down to the node that ends up doing the sequential scan on `t2` when the index isn't used. (On the real system, all rows from “t2” are returned, only to have most of them thrown away by the `limit` at the very end).

Comment: I suggest you post a more minimal question.  I guess that most users won't have the time to read through so many complex explain plans.

Comment: I don't see the problem. The tables seem to be empty, and the query executes fast. You should provide a test case that shows the PostgreSQL is choosing the wrong (slow) plan.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Fair point. Updated the examples now.

Comment: I cannot access this link. Please post the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as text in the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added link to the text versions below the images now.

Comment: I have replaced the link with text. Can you try to set `enable_hashjoin` and `enable_mergejoin` to `off` and run the query again? Does that plan look more like what you envision? Is the execution faster?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the suggestion. Posgres still did a sequential scan of `t2` and then a nested loop for the `left join`: https://lpaste.com/ha2J8I5six

Comment: Replacing the `LEFT JOIN` by a plain `JOIN` won't harm here. OOPS! But: why are there separate `t1` and `t2` tables?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the optimizer isn't smart enough to do the best thing if there is a `UNION ALL` involved.

One solution is to write the query in a more complicated way that helps the optimizer to figure out what is the best thing to do. You have to do without the view for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT t1.id, t1.n, t1.updated, null
       FROM t1
       ORDER BY t1.updated DESC
       LIMIT 10)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT t2.id, t2.n, t2.updated, a.x
       FROM t2
          LEFT JOIN aux2 a ON a.id = t2.id
       ORDER BY t2.updated DESC
       LIMIT 10)
     ) AS q
ORDER BY updated DESC                                                 
LIMIT 10;
```